# OpenWrt Backfire 10.03 Frequently Becoming Unresponsive (Bridged Client)

Tags: wireless-networking, openwrt

I have a Linksys WRT54G version 2 that I've flashed with OpenWrt Backfire 10.03. It's acting as a [bridged client using the wl.o driver](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/recipes/bridgedclient) to give me network access in my home office, which is in a far corner of my house in a position that would make it exceedingly difficult to fish network cabling in through the walls. I have three network-ready devices attached to the device that don't currently support WiFi, including a networked printer.

Ever since I migrated from WhiteRussian, which was also set up as a bridged client, to Backfire, the device has been becoming unresponsive, as though the OS itself has crashed or frozen. The WLAN light becomes completely solid and the LAN lights stay mostly solid, blipping off and then back on again maybe once a second or so. They all blink more or less in unison.

Is there some way I can diagnose why this is happening so I can fix it? Right now, the only way to fix it is to unplug the device and plug it back in.

Comment: I've noticed something rather interesting... It seems like the freezing/crashing only occurs when I'm running Steam on my desktop PC (Windows XP SP3). It hasn't occurred since I disabled Steam from auto-starting. I'll try running Steam again to see if that changes anything.

Answer (score 0):

Chris I would start by monitoring the device with a SSH connection to the bridged device from a machine on your network, if you use windows you will have to get a SSH client like putty.  From that terminal run

> tail -f  /varlog/messages (I think it's messages, I will double check in a second)

and leave the terminal open and go about your business. When the router locks up you should have a record of the last bit of events that happened and can start troubleshooting from there.

[Here](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/uci/system) is a link the system setup of openwrt to ensure that logging is enabled and where it is directed.

Comment: one should use "logread"
there are no persistent log files in default config

Answer (score 0):

backfire 10.3.1 is out. backup config, upgrade, restore config.
you do not mention any wireless clients. Why not using normal wireless bridge instead. wl.o eats memory and you do not have plenty of it.

Proper log reading command is "logread"

Comment: I needed a way to connect my networked printer to my network, but my printer only supported a wired connection. Naturally, I needed my printer to be on the same subnet as the rest of my network. Enter wl.o.